# Disable MySQL replication on rds

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-rds, aws, amazon-ec2

I want set up replication between an Amazon RDS MySQL DB instance and a MySQL  instance that is external to Amazon RDS.

but  Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
how to solve this problem?

I have already done the following commands.

```
mysql>CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master ('192.168.xx.xxx', 3306,
    'repl2', '111111', 'mysql-bin-changelog.000003', 598, 0); 

mysql> CALL mysql.rds_start_replication; 

+-------------------------+
| Message                 |
+-------------------------+
| Slave running normally. |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (1.01 sec)
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you mask `192.168.xx.xxx` ?

Comment: I don't get it. What are you trying to achieve exactly ? Do you have a replication already in use ? From where to where ? Who will be the master ?

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to disable replication is to run this on the RDS slave

```
CALL mysql.rds_stop_replication;
CALL mysql.rds_reset_external_master;
```

If `Slave_IO_Running` is `Connecting`, then there is one or both of the issues

- The grants for the `repl2` user is wrong
- firewall issue on port 3306.

If the issue is the grants, drop the `repl2` and add it back with

```
DROP USER 'repl2'@'%';
CREATE USER 'repl2'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '111111';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE,REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'repl2'@'%';
```

I'll leave the FW/SecurityGroup stuff to you.

Once these are cleared up, run the `CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master` with the proper private IP. Please don't use `192.168.x.x`.